# How to clear Fragment backstack in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

hi how to clear fragment back stack am using below logic it's not working...

```
for(int i = 0; i < mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {            
     mFragmentManager.popBackStack();
}
```

help me..

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Try this

```
mFragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: Please elaborate as this is one of the best solutions. You may have to call popBackStackImmediate instead if you are adding new stuff to the backstack right after clearing it.

Comment: This would only pop the top state, not clear the backstack if more than one.

Comment: This loads the previous Fragment before commit the transaction with the new Fragment. You can't see it but programmatically is calling `onActivityCreated()` of the previous Fragment before the new one.

Comment: @VasileM and how do we overcome that?

Answer (score 82):

Answer above is almost correct, but you need a guard around the fragment back list as it can be empty:

```
private void clearBackStack() {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (manager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        FragmentManager.BackStackEntry first = manager.getBackStackEntryAt(0);
         manager.popBackStack(first.getId(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer I've found so far which acknowledges the actual issue. Kudos.

Answer (score 20):

```
while (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer if you elaborated more. Clearing the whole backstack is what we want

Comment: But it shows the last one. Usually, after that you just add new fragment to backstack.

Comment: One caveat here is that popping the backstack in a loop like this will call lifecycle events in all of the fragments it pops (the creation methods as well as the shutdown methods), which might leave you with unintended side effects.

Answer (score 17):

one way is to *tag* the `backstack` and when you want to clear it

```
mFragmentManager.popBackStack("myfancyname", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

where the `"myfancyname"` should match the string you used with `addToBackStack`. E.g.

```
Fragment fancyFragment = new FancyFragment();     
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_container, fancyFragment, "myfragmentag");
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("myfancyname");
```

the `backstack`'s name and the fragment's tag name can be the same but there are no constrains on this regard

From the documentation

> If set, and the name or ID of a back stack entry has been supplied,
>   then all matching entries will be consumed until one that doesn't
>   match is found or the bottom of the stack is reached. Otherwise, all
>   entries up to but not including that entry will be removed.

if you don't want to use a name for your backstack you can pass use a first parameter

```
 mFragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: How do you give name to backstack?

Comment: Gokhan, the name is not the name of the backstack, it's the Fragment's tag name. For his example, the Fragment that he's popping would have been added like this:


`mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(mFragment, "myfancyname");`

Answer (score 12):

This is a bit late but I just had this problem myself. You can do:

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentManager.BackStackEntry first = manager.getBackStackEntryAt(0);
manager.popBackStack(first.getId(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

Pretty self explanatory; you just get the first entry, get its id, and then pop everything up to and including the entry with that id.

Answer (score 0):

The best option I ever seen is here.

```
            int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
            if (count > 0) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            }
```