# going to first fragment from anywhere when pressing back button using backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I have a `HomeFragment1`, `ClassFragment2`, `QuestionFragment3`, `LastFragment4`. The user will navigate in the order mentioned. I want to return to HomeFragment1 from anywhere the user presses back button.

I tried removing addToBackStack in all fragments except HomeFragment1 but when pressing back button the fragments overlap.

I wrote in the onBackPressed() of the MainActivity as below:

```
if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ) {
    fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
} else {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

But it returns from 4 to 3 to 2 to 1 in this order for each back press. I would like to go directly to 1 from any fragment.

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28360913/popbackstack-but-keep-the-first-fragment-in-android

Comment: fragmentManager.popBackStack ("fragmentATagName", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

Comment: This link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992216/android-fragment-handle-back-button-press the same like your question issues you can try it.

Comment: This link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992216/android-fragment-handle-back-button-press the same like your question.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is:

1) It is necessary to add all fragments to backstack using `addToBackStack("text")`. **Because not adding any fragment to backstack will make it overlap with previous fragment when back pressed**.

2) Then we need to clear the backstack using following lines of code which should be added to `onBackPressed()` overridden method.

```java
if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(getSupportFragmentManager()
    .getBackStackEntryAt(0).getId(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
} else {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

or simply

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

There are a lot of answers found for this question as mentioned below but the one worked for me is above.

[Is this the right way to clean-up Fragment back stack when leaving a deeply nested stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802141/is-this-the-right-way-to-clean-up-fragment-back-stack-when-leaving-a-deeply-nest/26093368#26093368)

[Clear back stack using fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186433/clear-back-stack-using-fragments)

[PopBackStack but keep the first fragment in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28360913/popbackstack-but-keep-the-first-fragment-in-android)

[How to clear Fragment backstack in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107005/how-to-clear-fragment-backstack-in-android/20591748)

Thanks to @Ankit Aman for the link.